# $|f|$ has a relative maximum at $z_0$ implies $f$ is constant in a neighborhood of $z_0$

Tags: complex-analysis

I'm trying to understand the proof of the following statement: Let $f$ be analytic in a connected region $A$ and let $z_0\in A$. If $|f|$ has a relative maximum at $z_0$ then $f(z)$ is constant in a neighborhood of $z_0$.

Proof: Let $C$ be a circle around $z_0$ small enough so that $|f(z)|\leq |f(z_0)|$ for $z\in C$. By the mean value property, $$|f(z_0)|=\big| \frac{1}{2\pi}\int_0^{2\pi}f(z_0+re^{i\theta})d\theta\big|\leq \frac{1}{2\pi}\int_0^{2\pi}|f(z_0+re^{i\theta})|d\theta\leq \frac{1}{2\pi}\int_0^{2\pi}|f(z_0)|d\theta=|f(z_0)|.$$
So all the inequalities actually are equalities. Now, here is what I don't understand: The proof argues that the first inequality can only be an equality if for all $\theta$, $f(z_0+re^{i\theta})$ lie on the same ray from the origin. Why is that?

Comment: You forgot the  most important hypothesis: you need $f$ to be analytic.

Answer (score 1):

Let $|\int_a^{b} g(x)dx|=\int_a^{b} |g(x)|dx$ where $g$ is a complex valued continuous function. Let $\int_a^{b} g(x)dx=re^{i\theta}$ be the polar form of the integral.

Then $\int_a^{b} |g(x)|dx=r=\int_a^{b} [e^{-i\theta}g(x)]dx$. Take real parts on both sides.  Let $h(x)=|g(x)|- \Re [e^{-i\theta}g(x)]$. Then $h \geq 0$ and  $\int_a^{b} h(x)dx=0$. This implies that $h=0$. Hence $|g(x)|= \Re [e^{-i\theta}g(x)]$ which implies that the imaginary part of  $e^{-i\theta}g(x)$ is $0$. So $g(x)=|g(x)|e^{i\theta}$, as required.